# Flutter: show facebook friends who also use the app

Tags: facebook, flutter, dart

I have a flutter application where you can sign in with Facebook. (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login).

When a user logs in, I create a new FireStore document (the document has the user ID as name). Within, I store other info such as email etc.

The app allows to make 'friends', I do that now by implementing a search bar where you can search for users based on their name.

But is there a possibility to show a user a 'recommended friends' list, that contains all his facebook friends that are also using the app.

I thought of a list of all the fb ID's of his friends and comparing that to the ID's in Firestore? (is that possible with the fb package?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use user_friends Facebook api. You must before get permission to use it from Facebook. It returns only user friends that are using same application.